# What is $Secure:$SDS:$DATA on Windows?

Tags: windows

One of my customers has seen $Secure:$SDS:$DATA show up on their drive and it keeps growing while my app is running.  I don't (knowingly) write to this file, and don't use any type of Windows secure storage (which might be related).  Kind of stumped...

Any thoughts on what this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather it's a metafile for NTFS. Does your app handle anything related to user access or NTFS permissions on files?

Comment: My app does change permissions on some files that it creates (it's a service, so it adds permissions so other users can access them -- mostly log files, and only a limited number of them).  I don't find that file on my machines, but one customer has one that is continually growing, and is now 1GB.

Comment: Looks like you are right. Not sure why it's getting so big....   http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-security-descriptor.htm